# Understanding Rails logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Request logs are shown in a format, which starts with something like below:

```
I, [2018-03-21T00:32:28.779383 #20153]  INFO -- : method=GET
```

I never had any interest about this but now I am curious to know, what that number **#20153** represents ? Is that process id or database connection id or something else ?

This application uses Passenger app server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log format you posted here is the [default logging format](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#class-Logger-label-Format) of Ruby’s own `Logger` class, which looks like this:

```
SeverityID, [DateTime #pid] SeverityLabel -- ProgName: message
```

So yes, the number after the timestamp you’re seeing in your logs is the process ID.